# Cast ArrayList<String> to String[] in one expression?

Tags: java, exception, casting, super

I have a constructor that accepts an `ArrayList<String>`, but wants to call `super` expecting a `String[]` array.

I have tried the following, but it results in a class exception, `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;`

```
public cool(ArrayList<String> s) {
    super((String[]) s.toArray());
}
```

I'd like to be able to pass `cool` an `ArrayList<String>`

Thanks

EDIT:  I have tried the recent suggestion to use

```
super(s.toArray(new String[s.size()]));
```

but now I get the following exception:

`entity must have a no-arg constructor.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: : entity must have a no-arg constructor.`

Comment: No need to cast (as usual)... check out the API for [List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: Oh, so this is an annotated entity. You must provide a default constructor (one with no args at all) in order for it to be instantiated by whatever framework you're using.

Comment: @Gamb  oops, you are right.  I have these in a bunch of classes, but this one must have slipped my mind!  thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
super(s.toArray(new String[s.size()]));
```

The above is the type-safe way to convert an `ArrayList` into an array, it's not a really *cast*, just a conversion.

Regarding the new error reported - you have to declare a no-arg constructor in the entity mentioned in the error.

Comment: (+1) Note that there are casts that take place here, they're just hidden from you by the implementation.

Comment: @Óscar López Thanks it fixed my initial problem.

Comment: @StephenD see my edit, the second error is not directly related to the first, it's rather a rule that all entity objects must follow: they must explicitly have a constructor without arguments